# CombinePerKey not merging accumulators across multiple workers

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am building a calculation pipeline that writes metrics to BigQuery. At one point in the pipeline, I have over 50M key-value pairs that need to be grouped by key with calculations done on the grouped values. I am using a `CombinePerKey` with custom `CombineFn` accumulators. After the `CombinePerKey` is complete, the results of the accumulated values are written to BigQuery.

When the pipeline is run on Dataflow, the work is spread across over 50 workers. This is resulting in over 40 metrics with identical keys and different values being written to BigQuery. When the input is small enough to be run on one worker, it produces the output I expect (only one output for each unique key with correct aggregated values.) How can I design this so that the values are combined for the same key even across multiple workers?

Here is the full pipeline:

```
def run(argv=None):
    """Runs the recidivism calculation pipeline."""

    # Workaround to load SQLAlchemy objects at start of pipeline. This is
    # necessary because the BuildRootEntity function tries to access attributes
    # of relationship properties on the SQLAlchemy room_schema_class before they
    # have been loaded. However, if *any* SQLAlchemy objects have been
    # instantiated, then the relationship properties are loaded and their
    # attributes can be successfully accessed.
    _ = schema.StatePerson()

    # Parse command-line arguments
    known_args, pipeline_args = parse_arguments(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    # Get pipeline job details
    all_pipeline_options = pipeline_options.get_all_options()

    query_dataset = all_pipeline_options['project'] + '.' + known_args.input

    with beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args) as p:
        # Get StatePersons
        persons = (p
                   | 'Load Persons' >>
                   BuildRootEntity(dataset=query_dataset,
                                   data_dict=None,
                                   root_schema_class=schema.StatePerson,
                                   root_entity_class=entities.StatePerson,
                                   unifying_id_field='person_id',
                                   build_related_entities=True))

        # Get StateIncarcerationPeriods
        incarceration_periods = (p
                                 | 'Load IncarcerationPeriods' >>
                                 BuildRootEntity(
                                     dataset=query_dataset,
                                     data_dict=None,
                                     root_schema_class=
                                     schema.StateIncarcerationPeriod,
                                     root_entity_class=
                                     entities.StateIncarcerationPeriod,
                                     unifying_id_field='person_id',
                                     build_related_entities=True))

        # Get StateSupervisionViolationResponses
        supervision_violation_responses = \
            (p
             | 'Load SupervisionViolationResponses' >>
             BuildRootEntity(
                 dataset=query_dataset,
                 data_dict=None,
                 root_schema_class=schema.StateSupervisionViolationResponse,
                 root_entity_class=entities.StateSupervisionViolationResponse,
                 unifying_id_field='person_id',
                 build_related_entities=True
             ))

        # Group StateIncarcerationPeriods and StateSupervisionViolationResponses
        # by person_id
        incarceration_periods_and_violation_responses = (
            {'incarceration_periods': incarceration_periods,
             'violation_responses': supervision_violation_responses}
            | 'Group StateIncarcerationPeriods to '
              'StateSupervisionViolationResponses' >>
            beam.CoGroupByKey()
        )

        # Set the fully hydrated StateSupervisionViolationResponse entities on
        # the corresponding StateIncarcerationPeriods
        incarceration_periods_with_source_violations = (
            incarceration_periods_and_violation_responses
            | 'Set hydrated StateSupervisionViolationResponses on '
            'the StateIncarcerationPeriods' >>
            beam.ParDo(SetViolationResponseOnIncarcerationPeriod()))

        # Group each StatePerson with their StateIncarcerationPeriods
        person_and_incarceration_periods = (
            {'person': persons,
             'incarceration_periods':
                 incarceration_periods_with_source_violations}
            | 'Group StatePerson to StateIncarcerationPeriods' >>
            beam.CoGroupByKey()
        )

        # Identify ReleaseEvents events from the StatePerson's
        # StateIncarcerationPeriods
        person_events = (
            person_and_incarceration_periods |
            'Get Release Events' >>
            GetReleaseEvents())

        # Get dimensions to include and methodologies to use
        inclusions, methodologies = dimensions_and_methodologies(known_args)

        # Get pipeline job details for accessing job_id
        all_pipeline_options = pipeline_options.get_all_options()

        # Add timestamp for local jobs
        job_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S.%f')
        all_pipeline_options['job_timestamp'] = job_timestamp

        # Get recidivism metrics
        recidivism_metrics = (person_events
                              | 'Get Recidivism Metrics' >>
                              GetRecidivismMetrics(
                                  pipeline_options=all_pipeline_options,
                                  inclusions=inclusions))

        filter_metrics_kwargs = {'methodologies': methodologies}

        # Filter out unneeded metrics
        final_recidivism_metrics = (
            recidivism_metrics
            | 'Filter out unwanted metrics' >>
            beam.ParDo(FilterMetrics(), **filter_metrics_kwargs))

        # Convert the metrics into a format that's writable to BQ
        writable_metrics = (final_recidivism_metrics
                            | 'Convert to dict to be written to BQ' >>
                            beam.ParDo(
                                RecidivismMetricWritableDict()).with_outputs(
                                    'rates', 'counts', 'liberties'))

        # Write the recidivism metrics to the output tables in BigQuery
        rates_table = known_args.output + '.recidivism_rate_metrics'
        counts_table = known_args.output + '.recidivism_count_metrics'
        liberty_table = known_args.output + '.recidivism_liberty_metrics'

        _ = (writable_metrics.rates
             | f"Write rate metrics to BQ table: {rates_table}" >>
             beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                 table=rates_table,
                 create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                 write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
             ))

        _ = (writable_metrics.counts
             | f"Write count metrics to BQ table: {counts_table}" >>
             beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                 table=counts_table,
                 create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                 write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
             ))

        _ = (writable_metrics.liberties
             | f"Write liberty metrics to BQ table: {liberty_table}" >>
             beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                 table=liberty_table,
                 create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                 write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
             ))
```

The transform that produces the large amount of key-value pairs and then does the `CombinePerKey` is `GetRecidivismMetrics`:

```
class GetRecidivismMetrics(beam.PTransform):
    """Transforms a StatePerson and ReleaseEvents into RecidivismMetrics."""

    def __init__(self, pipeline_options: Dict[str, str],
                 inclusions: Dict[str, bool]):
        super(GetRecidivismMetrics, self).__init__()
        self._pipeline_options = pipeline_options
        self.inclusions = inclusions

    def expand(self, input_or_inputs):
        # Calculate recidivism metric combinations from a StatePerson and their
        # ReleaseEvents
        recidivism_metric_combinations = (
            input_or_inputs
            | 'Map to metric combinations' >>
            beam.ParDo(CalculateRecidivismMetricCombinations(),
                       **self.inclusions).with_outputs('counts', 'rates',
                                                       'liberties'))

        # Calculate the recidivism count values for the metrics combined by key
        counts_with_sums = (recidivism_metric_combinations.counts
                            | 'Calculate recidivism counts values' >>
                            beam.CombinePerKey(SumFn()))

        # Calculate the recidivism rate values for the metrics combined by key
        rates_with_values = (recidivism_metric_combinations.rates
                             | 'Calculate recidivism rate values' >>
                             beam.CombinePerKey(RecidivismRateFn()))

        # Calculate the recidivism liberty values for metrics combined by key
        liberties_with_values = (recidivism_metric_combinations.liberties
                                 | 'Calculate time at liberty values' >>
                                 beam.CombinePerKey(RecidivismLibertyFn()))

        # Produce the ReincarcerationRecidivismCountMetrics
        counts_metrics = (counts_with_sums
                          | 'Produce recidivism count metrics' >>
                          beam.ParDo(
                              ProduceReincarcerationRecidivismCountMetric(),
                              **self._pipeline_options))

        # Produce the ReincarcerationRecidivismRateMetrics
        rates_metrics = (rates_with_values
                         | 'Produce recidivism rate metrics' >>
                         beam.ParDo(
                             ProduceReincarcerationRecidivismMetric(),
                             **self._pipeline_options))

        # Produce the ReincarcerationRecidivismRateMetrics
        liberties_metrics = (liberties_with_values
                             | 'Produce recidivism liberty metrics' >>
                             beam.ParDo(
                                 ProduceReincarcerationRecidivismMetric(),
                                 **self._pipeline_options))

        # Merge the metric groups
        merged_metrics = ((counts_metrics, rates_metrics, liberties_metrics)
                          | 'Merge counts, rates, and liberties metrics' >>
                          beam.Flatten())

        # Return ReincarcerationRecidivismMetric objects
        return merged_metrics
```

Here's the `CalculateRecidivismMetricCombinations` DoFn:

```
class CalculateRecidivismMetricCombinations(beam.DoFn):
    """Calculates recidivism metric combinations."""

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        """Produces various recidivism metric combinations.

        Sends the calculator the StatePerson entity and their corresponding
        ReleaseEvents for mapping all recidivism combinations.

        Args:
            element: Tuple containing a StatePerson and their ReleaseEvents
            **kwargs: This should be a dictionary with values for the
                following keys:
                    - age_bucket
                    - gender
                    - stay_length_bucket
                    - release_facility
                    - race
                    - ethnicity
        Yields:
            Each recidivism metric combination, tagged by metric type.
        """

        person, release_events = element

        # Calculate recidivism metric combinations for this person and events
        metric_combinations = \
            calculator.map_recidivism_combinations(person,
                                                   release_events, kwargs)

        # Return each of the recidivism metric combinations
        for metric_combination in metric_combinations:
            metric_key, value = metric_combination

            # Freezing the metric key as a set so it is hashable
            frozen_metric_key = frozenset(metric_key.items())

            if metric_key.get('metric_type') == 'rate':
                yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput('rates',
                                               (frozen_metric_key, value))
            elif metric_key.get('metric_type') == 'count':
                yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput('counts',
                                               (frozen_metric_key, value))
            elif metric_key.get('metric_type') == 'liberty':
                yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput('liberties',
                                               (frozen_metric_key, value))
```

The `map_recidivism_combinations` function produces thousands of dictionaries per person that become the keys which are later grouped across all people in the `CombinePerKey` calls.

**Solution**

It seems that `frozenset` is does not have deterministic output when run on multiple machines. Therefore, when a Dataflow job was run on multiple workers, identical keys were being converted to non-identical frozensets. Converting the dictionary keys to JSON strings with sorted keys solved the problem.

Comment: `CombinePerKey` should be accumulating values across different workers for the same key and window. Are you that these are not values for the same key (across workers) executed for different windows ?

Comment: The data set is bounded, so they should all be in the same window.

Comment: Can you share your pipeline ? Note that bounded pipelines can support windows but if you don't specify a window function everything will be in the Global window.

Comment: Added context to the original question.

Comment: Found the issue: it seems that `frozenset` is does not have deterministic output when run on multiple machines. Converting our dictionary keys to JSON strings with sorted keys solved the problem.